# STUR X9,[X2,X12]

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

Assume a number in stored in the register X12 and X2 is the address and X9 has another number, Does this work? STUR X9,[X2,X12]

Comment: You forgot to specify architecture. As to whether it works, consult the manual, and/or try it in a sample program. Also, in what way is it `C`?

Comment: No, according to the manual you can't add two registers in the address. You'll have to do it yourself beforehand.

Comment: Depends what you want to do too, if you wanted to add them together then no this doesn't work. What's your expected behaviour / problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a register offset addressing mode to store a register you can use the `STR` instruction. So the following:

```
str x9, [x2, x12]
```

assembles just fine for aarch64 and disassembles as

```
f82c6849    str x9, [x2, x12]
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  This would result in the following:

```
Error: invalid addressing mode at operand 2 --...
```

According to the ARMv8 Instruction Set Overview,  you must use an immediate (i.e., #simm9) for the second operand.